# What is the red hat service, "pand?"

Tags: redhat

This is for RHEL 5.6. I am trying to search through the documentation from Red Hat's site and nothing is coming up about what this service is or what it does. Does anyone know what "pand" is? The closest I can find anywhere is that it may have something to do with bluetooth ad-hoc networking. I'd appreciate it if anyone has any better ideas.

Comment: 802.15 Wireless Personal Area Networks (wPAN) aka Bluetooth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pand` is a part of the `bluez-utils`-package.  From it's man page:

> The pand PAN daemon allows your computer to connect to ethernet networks using Bluetooth.

Comment: PAN is a Personal Area Network. As opposed to a LAN (Local Area Network).

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the man page?

```
 man pand
```

You can do:

```
 rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/pand
```

to find out which package provides this program (bluez-utils).

You can then look at /usr/share/doc/bluez-utils-3.7 (current version on my system). And using the pointers contained in the files go from there to find more information.

I'll presume google searching would also turn up something as well.

Comment: Or if rpm is too unafamiliar, you can get yum to tell you `yum provides /usr/bin/pand` and find out more information about the package itself `yum info bluez-compat`

Answer (score 1):

To allow an IP network to be set up over bluetooth, 
[pand HOWTO](http://bluez.sourceforge.net/contrib/HOWTO-PAN)